# UrbanAirship - Where is a setting for 'Allow Push From Device' in the admin page?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I read the [urbanairship documentation](https://urbanairship.com/docs/push_index.html#allow-push-from-device) about how to 'Allow Push [notificaition] From Device' and in the document, it said there should be an option to do so. However, when I am in the admin page of my app. I cannot see that option. I saw that I can edit: Application name, Application Icon, Category, Rich Push Enabled, Push Notification Support, Apple push certificate, Certificate password, Push debug mode, BlackBerry stuff...,Android stuff.

Where is an option to 'Allow Push From Device'? Am I looking at the right Admin page? Is the doc out-of-date?

Thank you very much for any helps or guidances!

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer on [their support pages](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/369452-allow-push-from-device):

> Thank you for contacting us. We made a change to the system that for any new apps created, that option would no longer be available. If you send us an email to support@urbanairship.com with your app key and original request, we can turn this on for you.